# Ionic : Ion-slides- Only First Slide appearing

Tags: angular, ionic3, ion-slides

I'm trying to add ion-slides to my app, but i'm facing a problem that i don't have any idea how to solve it. 
I simple added the ion-slides example to my page:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Test3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And even with this simple example, the component just shows the first slide. When i try to swipe to the next one, it shows a blank slide, even though it's possible to inspect this element and it's content.

Do you have any ideas regarding this?

I didn't put more code here, because not even this code is working.
I suspected that the problem was happening because i was trying to create this element in a Tab page, so I've tried to add this element into another page, but i still had the same behavior.

Comment: i've tested it, it's working fine. try to restart the project

Comment: Hello there, i've tried to restart, rebuild, but it still not working. I've created another project and then it worked.

Comment: ok great then :)

Comment: But @Raed, thats not a solution for me.  My project is too far developed to star a new project, just because of that.

Comment: maybe the versions used in the original project is not compatible with ionic-slides, try to open package.json file in both project and match the versions, and try to upgrade the old ones related to ionic-slides

Comment: Both of them have same version:"ionic-angular": "3.9.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. 
When I started developing the application I set overflow attribute as hiddden for all Elements. So i had to make some changes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Write your ion-clides code inside the ion-content
or its not work then try [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/slides/basic)...